# How does CV_OCL_RUN macro work in goodFeaturesToTrack implementation from OpenCV (version 3.4.5)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I was taking a look at goodFeaturesToTrack implementation from OpenCV (version 3.4.5, file modules/imgproc/src/featureselect.cpp) and found the CV_OCL_RUN macro inside of it. I don't know anything about OpencCL but I understand the preprocessor mechanisms typically used in C. I don't understand how this is supposed to work:

```
void cv::goodFeaturesToTrack( InputArray _image, OutputArray _corners,
                              int maxCorners, double qualityLevel, double minDistance,
                              InputArray _mask, int blockSize, int gradientSize,
                              bool useHarrisDetector, double harrisK )
{
    CV_INSTRUMENT_REGION();

    CV_Assert( qualityLevel > 0 && minDistance >= 0 && maxCorners >= 0 );
    CV_Assert( _mask.empty() || (_mask.type() == CV_8UC1 && _mask.sameSize(_image)) );

    CV_OCL_RUN(_image.dims() <= 2 && _image.isUMat(),
               ocl_goodFeaturesToTrack(_image, _corners, maxCorners, qualityLevel, minDistance,
                                    _mask, blockSize, gradientSize, useHarrisDetector, harrisK))

    Mat image = _image.getMat(), eig, tmp;
    if (image.empty())
    {
        _corners.release();
        return;
    }
    .
    .
    .
```

Let's suppose this is compiled with OpenCL support so where the macro CV_OCL_RUN is, the function ocl_goodFeaturesToTrack is effectively called. After that, would not the execution continue to the lines of code intended for versions without OpenCL? I can think of other macros defined at a higher level that could make that if you have OpenCL support then the function I am looking at would not be called but I did not find any other part where it is defined.

Comment: "would not the execution continue" -- not if that macro contains a return statement in the branch that runs the OpenCL implementation... which it [does](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/5dd46b54c10b4d18041598eb0f96d062cc8420fe/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/ocl_defs.hpp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding the situation, the function would not continue executing - the macro contains a return statement.

Have a look at the possible options of what CV_OCL_RUN can expand to:
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/opencl/ocl_defs.hpp

All three variants of CV_OCL_RUN_ return if the OpenCL route is taken: lines 36, 57 and 67.

Comment: Can't believe I did not see that. Thank you!